# Python - Creating egg file what is the use of description and long description

Tags: python, setup.py, egg

I am creating an egg file and I am able to do that successfully.  However, the value I have provided in description and long_description is not visible.

**setup.py**

```
description = "desc"
long_description = "lond desc"
setup(
    name="abc",
    version="0.2",
    packages=find_packages(),
    description=description,
    long_description=long_description,
    author='Gaurang Shah',
    author_email='gaurang.shah@abc.com'

)
```

**Build script**

```
rm -rf build dist dataplaform.egg-info
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

After installing a package, when I run following command. I don't see anything?

```
import abc
abc.__doc__
```

Answer (score 0):

You would see `description` and/or `long_description` on `pip show abc` or on the [PyPI repository](https://pypi.org/project/abc/). Basically on places that refer to the **Python project** `abc`.

When you type `import abc; print(abc.__doc__)` you refer to a **Python top level package** (or module) `abc` that *coincidentally* has been made available by installing the distribution (in this case a `bdist_egg`) of a project bearing the same name `abc`.

Python projects and Python packages are not the same thing though. The confusion comes from the fact that it is almost always the case that a Python project contains a single top level package of the same name, and so both are used interchangeably to great confusion. See [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for a famous counter example.

In your case `abc.__doc__` actually refers to the *docstring* of your `abc/__init__.py` (or eventually a top level `abc.py`).

Comment: @Gaurang did this answer your question?